# adding labels/categories to looped micropost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Hartl's screencast and we are iterating through microposts and showing them in the view:

```
<div class="span8">
  <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
    <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
    <ol class="microposts">
      <%= render @microposts %>
    </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I want to label each micropost (Micropost 1, Micropost 2, etc...). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= render @microposts %>` renders the partial *app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb*. So it should just be a case of editing that file.

In the tutorial, I believe the *micropost.html.erb* file looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td class="micropost">
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

To add a label, you could do something like:

```
<tr>
  <td class="micropost">
    <span class="label"><%= "Micropost #{micropost.id}" %><span>
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This will add the text 'Micropost 1', 'Micropost 2' ect above each of the microposts content

**Edit**

If you don't want to use ID and just want sequential numbering then you can change the code to iterate over each micropost and render them individually, passing in the count:

```
<% @microposts.all.each_with_index do |micropost, index| %>
  <%= render micropost, locals: {index: index} %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your partial you can use the local variable `index`:

```
<tr>
  <td class="micropost">
    <span class="label"><%= "Micropost #{index}" %><span>
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If it gets the microposts id as the number and say someone destroys a micro post wouldnt the numbering be off....I just want it to be numbered 1,2,3,4,5,etc for each

Comment: @RickyAhn Yes, you are correct, numbering using ids would be 'spoiled' if you deleted a record. I've updated my answer with a solution that should solve your problem.